# Sitecore User Group Mar 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are super excited to announce the March'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

JavaScript Services and Marketing Automation by [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) and [Rick Bauer](https://twitter.com/Sitecordial)

GDPR compliance with Sitecore implementation by [Paul Urban](https://twitter.com/urbansitecore)

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, Mar, 13, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, mar, 13, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/259073908/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began 17 hours ago